# How to determine the name of the active keyboard layout?

Tags: winapi

I can call `GetKeyboardLayout` to retrieve an "input locale identifier", which identifies the active layout in Windows. How can I convert this to a human-readable name, such as "English (United States)"?

`GetKeyboardLayoutName` is misleading - it just returns a string containing a hex version of the identifier retrieved by `GetKeyboardLayout`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20171216144224/http://easydesksoftware.com/keyboard.htm) is a list of keyboard layout names with their key names.

**Edit:**
I scanned registry and I found keyboard layout names on this location:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts